# How to count records as per all year?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to count record year wise, I did some query but i am not getting correct result. Below is my query. But that is not working for me. Can anyone please look in this and give me right query ? Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT id) FROM call_response WHERE  disposition=0 AND user_id=pu.id  ) AS `trueAlarm`, 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT id) FROM call_response WHERE  disposition=1 AND user_id=pu.id  ) AS `falseAlarm`, 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT id) FROM call_response WHERE  disposition=2 AND user_id=pu.id  ) AS `disregarded`, 
YEAR(cr.created_date) AS `callYear` 
FROM `call_response` AS `cr` 
INNER JOIN `permit_users` AS `pu` 
ON cr.user_id=pu.id 
WHERE ( pu.is_deleted=0 AND pu.is_trashed=0 AND cr.is_deleted=0)
GROUP BY `callYear`
```

Comment: What are you expecting? What are you getting? Please be more specific in your question

Comment: Can you make a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: From the little information you gave, my guess would go for these sub distinct select.
Does removing all 3 of them make the request return something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you want uses either conditional aggregation or subqueries, but not both.  In other words, either use the subqueries but do not have an outer join to `call_response`.  Or, have the outer join but not the subqueries.

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT count(distinct case when disposition = 0 AND user_id = pu.id then id end) as trueAlarm, 
       count(distinct case when disposition = 1 AND user_id = pu.id then id end) as falseAlarm, 
       count(distinct case when disposition = 2 AND user_id = pu.id then id end) as disregarded, 
       YEAR(cr.created_date) AS `callYear` 
FROM `call_response` `cr` INNER JOIN
     `permit_users` `pu` 
      ON cr.user_id = pu.id 
WHERE pu.is_deleted = 0 AND pu.is_trashed = 0 AND cr.is_deleted = 0
GROUP BY `callYear`;
```

Comment: +1, what i though but you put it in way better words ;)